# Native or jQuery for a large web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, post

I know that coding in native JavaScript means that your code will execute faster than if you were to code it in jQuery, but how much faster?

In particular, I want to know if the speed increase would make it worth while spending the longer time coding in native JavaScript than jQuery if it was for a very large webapp?

Or is the difference in speed not that great at all?

For instance, to setup an AJAX request in jQuery all you have to do is call `$.ajax` or `$.post` and pass a few parameters, but with native JavaScript you have to create `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` objects depending on the users browser etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in speed is in milliseconds - which can add up with thousands of jQuery calls.

The reason is that with jQuery, it tests different scenarios by the information you feed it, so it can function in many ways - even in ways that you will never use. For the functions you DO use, jQuery still performs tests on possible variables and scenarios that you will never feed it for your particular app.

That is what makes it slower. It really depends on how many calls to jQuery you will be making.

Although, it is also very cross-browser compatible, which is a big plus.

I would recommend jQuery personally, for many reasons. But again, it depends on how heavy you will need to use it, and what you define as a "great" difference.

Comment: Thanks, the importance of the cross-browser capabilities had slipped my mind. They are vital to my app.

Comment: You're welcome! And the cross-browser issues are a NIGHTMARE when trying to code yourself! Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to do is an AJAX request you can create your own mini-framework that wraps creating XMLHttpRequest and doing the browser dependent stuff.

The same way you could do for any other feature you need.

However: things are getting complex quite fast. Think about animations. jQuery or any other framework will do it better and faster. And cross browser tested.

Do yourself a favor and use an existing Framework.

One more thing: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. First find the bottleneck in your application, then optimize that part.

Answer (score 1):

Test it.

Pick a part of your web app and write it in JavaScript and then do the equivalent using jQuery. Test the performance.

Developing JavaScript that outperforms jQuery is dependent on your, or the team's skill. jQuery is battle hardened code that abstracts lots of browser quirks for you. It does add some overhead to cater for lots of development use cases but that is a price that many developers are willing to pay.

It takes skill and knowledge to to re-create the same functionality in JavaScript while eliminating the overhead that is not needed for your web app.

I recommend you use jQuery. However, once jQuery is part of your web app it becomes your code so you must make efforts to understand what it is doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I think the best way is to use jQuery instead of native JS. Especially if your app need support in IE6-IE8. Most of the time you'll spend on fixing crossbrowser issues instead of focusing on development.

Even if you'll make your own "mini-framework" for your needs I don't think this won't be with such quality and fast as jQuery. But if you'll use jQuery - follow best practices, and you won't have performance problems and your code will smaller and easy to read.

I think you should only use native JS in highly specialized web apps.

Answer (score 0):

On the app I'm building we are using a combination of JQuery with our own prototypes. The time difference from a user's perspective is negligible from using just straight JS. Plus the CBS(cross browser support) is super important.